# Displaying several results from a MySql database with Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am currently using the following code to load news announcements from my database.

```
            <?php 
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM news");
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                if($row->active == 1)
                {
                    echo "<p>".$row->content."</p>";
                }
            }
        ?>
```

However, I am using this code inside my template file inside CodeIgniter. Is there a better way for me to do this so that the code is separated into the Model and Controller file as it is supposed to be?

I have found documentation on the CodeIgniter documentation site and it tells me to do the following above, but i would really like to stick to the way the framework is designed.

Comment: Why not do this in the Model/Controller and expose the data to the view?

Comment: The issue with that is that I am VERY new to Code Igniter so I am not entirely sure on how to do that yet.

Comment: @Nikolas Shaffer, please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I did CodeIgniter, but here's something.

**Controller**

You would have the following code in your controller which lets you send `$data` to a specific view.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM news");
$data = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
  {
    if($row->active == 1)
      {
        array_push($data, $row);
      }
  }
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

**View**

Then in your view, calling it `your_view.php` , you'd have access to the `$data` for looping through.

```
 <?php foreach($data as $row) { ?>
   <p> <?php $row->content ?> </p>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: OP wants to separate the database call, logic and output. This answer only demonstrates the VC of MVC. :)

Comment: Well, if he is reading this, then I can say, he should checkout your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for the IF statement after the query?

**Model**

```
public function get_news() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE active = 1");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { // Only return if there is data
        foreach($query->result() AS $row) {
            $array[] = get_object_vars($row); // Just dump the values into an array
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->model('MODEL_NAME'); // Load the model that access the database
    $data['news'] = $this->MODEL_NAME->get_news(); // Assign the results of the function to the "news" index
    $this->load->view('view_page', $data); // Profit
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
    foreach($news AS $row) {
        echo '<p>' . $row['content'] . '</p>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I attempted this solution today and had a "better" response then I did with the one from Ali yet this issue is still perplexing me. For every row the query returns, i get a corresponding error instead of the news displayed properly. Error: Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: That's my bad. The array isn't returned as an object. Updated the view example accordingly.